# What are most commonly used keyboard shortcuts in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio

can you please share keyboard shortcuts that you used regularly in Visual Studio 2015 or 2017. Also if you can share the link to download keyboard scheme for visual studio. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Studio Keyboard Short Cuts](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2015/) This covers version(s) 2012-2017